# apt-get seems to be broken

Tags: apt, package-management

I don't really know what happened, but it seems like my apt-get command in ubuntu is broken. No matter what I do, I cannot use it to either install or uninstall anything. Right now, I am for example trying to install GAP:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install gap
Reading package lists... Done
:~$
```

Or maybe I want to uninstall vlc:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc
Reading package lists... Done
:~$
```

Or even if I want to uninstall something that isn't installed:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge some_nonexistant_package_that_doesnt_exist
Reading package lists... Done
:~$
```

Now all this only makes sense if the command apt-get itself is broken. Is there any way to reinstall apt-get itself? I can't really use apt-get to do that...

The `apt` command behaves much the same way:

```
:~$ sudo apt install gapp
Reading package lists... Done
:~$
```

Comment: Can you try to use `apt` instead of `apt-get` and post your results into your question?

Comment: @Videonauth Did that too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmm proken is it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution might be to download the apt package from this [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt), if your OS is not 16.04 do a search on this site for the right version for your version number of ubuntu. Then install it by:

```
# alter the name of the package accordingly
dpkg -i apt_1.2.10ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: That would be `trusty`, here is the link to the search results ([Link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apt&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)). Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Im glad you got it back working this way, then you can accept my answer so this question not stays in unanswered state :)

Comment: I already accepted, maybe the server needs some time to register...